# How to get parameter in __EVENTTARGET on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I use __doPostBack() in `<a>` tag as `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('clickDownload', 'data')">`.

And this tag is created dynamically in javascript. I wander how to get value of parameters in `__doPostBack('', '')`.

I refer to this site [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-excecute-a-c-Method-63380306), help me.

## .aspx.cs

```
public partial class Notice : App_Code.BasePage
{
    private int page = 1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.Expires = -1;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            (...)
        }

        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "clickDownload")
        {
            clickDownload(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void clickDownload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to here get value of parameters(i) about __doPostBack().
    }
}
```

## .aspx

```
<script>
    var fileText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fileText += '<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(\'clickDownload\', \'' + i + '\')"> test </a>';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code-behind, the parameter can be retrieved by:

```
string parameter = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```